# Argument of type 'DateInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), I want to use my local models instead of fullcalendar's model, and I when I'm trying to create new instance of my own model it says:

> Argument of type 'DateInput' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Date'.

Here is my `event.model.ts`:

```
export class EventModel {
  public eventId: string;
  public eventName: string;      
  public eventStart: Date;

  constructor(
    eventId: string,
    eventName: string,  
    eventStart: Date
  ) 
  {
    this.eventId = eventId;
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.eventStart = eventStart;
  }
}
```

Here is the fullcalendar initiation:

```
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
```

Usage:

```
private events: EventInput[] = [
    { id: "1", title: 'Test', start: new Date() }
];

getEvent(id: string) : EventModel {
    var event = this.events.find(x => x.id === id);        
    if (event) {
        EventModel model = new EventModel(event.id, event.title, event.start); //the event.start Throws error!
    } 
}
```

Comment: Presumably the type of a `EventInput.start` is `DateInput`, so did you look at the library docs or the type definition to see how to get a date out of that?

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe right! thanks a lot

Comment: The `start: new Date()` got me confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe comment insight.

Even though the `EventInput`'s start attribute has been initiate with simple `start: new Date()`:

```
private events: EventInput[] = [
    { id: "1", title: 'Event Now', start: new Date() }
];
```

The `EventInput` class looks like:

```
export interface EventDateInput {       
    start?: DateInput;
    //rest of properties.
}
```

`DateInput` is:

```
export type DateInput = Date | string | number | number[];
```

So a simple casting solve it:

```
EventModel model = new EventModel(event.id, event.title, <Date>event.start);
```